# Groovy regex for custom placeholders

Tags: regex, groovy

I have this groovy code:

```
s = "\${FirstAttribute} - DPA - \${Second Name}"
log.warn(s)
regex = "\\" + "\$\\{\\w+\\s*\\w*\\}"
log.warn(regex)

matcher = ( s=~ regex )
log.warn("" + matcher.matches())
if (matcher.matches()) {
    log.warn(matcher.getCount()+ " occurrence of the regular expression was found in the string.");
    log.warn(matcher[0] + " found!")
}
```

The idea is to match ${} containers and extract their content. According to [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/g8ih5E/1), the regex should be working. However, it works only when passing a string with one occurrence, like `"\${FirstAttribute} - DPA"` and if another occurence is present, there is nothing detected ( i.e.`matcher.matches() == false`)

I must be missing something very little, can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: `.matches()` requires a full string match.

Comment: You probably need to use the `/g` flag (Globl) or, most likely, you need to replace your logic to keep matching until it runs out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findAll` to get all the matches, but that doesn't allow groups as part of the matcher to just extract the middle bit:

```
s = '${FirstAttribute} - DPA - ${Second Name}'
regex = /\$\{[^}]+}/

assert s.findAll(regex) == ['${FirstAttribute}', '${Second Name}']
```